# Extending input with Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am following directions [as prescribed in the documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#type-extension) but the element does not get constructed. None of the lifecycle events are being called.

Note that when I remove the `extends: 'input'` property, I can see the lifecycle functions being called.

I'm using Polymer 1.8.1

Comment: So if you copy and paste the code shown in their example, "created" is not called?

Comment: @Bruce that's correct

Comment: I made sure my copy of polymer is 1.8.1 and I added an alert in the created method.  It seems to be get called twice actually: https://rawgit.com/bahrus/crystal/master/so_43294748.html .  You should b able to view source, to make sure we are talking about the same code snippet.  Can you share your code in a similar way?

Comment: @Bruce did you try adding `<my-input></my-input>` to the dom? I have no use of Polymer unless I'm able to use it declaratively. I use it to extend dom functionalities within [Elm](http://elm-lang.org).

Comment: Perhaps that's the confusion.  In Polymer 1.*, the markup would be <input is="my-input"> and that works for me

Comment: You shit me not!

Comment: @Bruce strange.. with the first render, it doesn't initialize. I then manually update the dom, and it initializes.